# How to add transistor model to LTspice?

Tags: transistors, bjt, ltspice, simulation, modeling

So, I'm an absolute beginner at LTSpice(I just started today).

I want to know how to add the model of transistor(say model ZTX300 or BC108) to my schematic.
I can't find the model in the standard.bjt file. So is there any way how to use them in LTSpice?

Comment: @SolarMike no how do I get the model data from the internet

Comment: How are you doing with the bjt library? Have you r3ead the helpfiles?

Comment: Why do you want to use exactly these BJT's in your simulation?  Because in 99% cases you can use any small-signal BJT you have LTspice. More you will find here http://bordodynov.ltwiki.org/

Comment: @G36 thanks, no I don't want to use a specific one.

Comment: What circuit do you want to simulate?

Comment: A transistor that you buy has a wide range of spec's. A simulator usually uses only the "typical" spec's then many of the circuits designed according to the simulator will not work properly. An old BC108 is the same as a modern BC548 but in a different case.

Comment: @vishbul2002 There normally should NOT be a need to have a specific model, as almost any discrete design that's worth anything doesn't depend upon specific device parameters. The exceptions are certain RF BJTs, certain high speed at high voltage change rates BJTs, etc., where you may need them. But then you'll have to deal with adding rarely applied schematic parasitics, too. That said, I have models for Philips and Zetex BC108A/B/C devices and can probably scare up the ZTX300 -- I know it's Early Effect is worse than normal, for example.

Comment: Have you tried googling "BC108 spice"?  Took me 5 seconds and I found a couple models, such as the ones in here:  http://espice.ugr.es/espice/src/modelos_subckt/spice_complete/zmodels.lib

Comment: @jonk well I did not know that I don't have to use a specific model. I was simulating an amplifier and a switch and my book mentioned these two so I started searching for them.

Comment: @SteKulov thanks it was not in the first page of searches in my case